# Spartacus custom styling - order of SCSS imports

Tags: css, angular, sass, spartacus-storefront

I am working on custom styles for my Spartacus application and struggling with the order of the CSS rendered. Despite the order of imports in my `styles.scss`, my custom CSS rules are rendered in the middle of Spartacus default styling, forcing me to bump up the specificity of my rules to achieve desired results.

This is my `styles.scss`:

```
$styleVersion: 4.3;
@import '~@spartacus/styles';

@import './styles/custom/_index';

/* custom/_index.scss contains further imports of the actual styling */
```

and this is the snippet of the rendered CSS:

```
/* Spartacus defaults 
...
*/

cx-wish-list-item .cx-return-button .btn-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* My custom code */

header .SiteLogo {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 150px;
}

/* Spartacus defaults continued */

cx-bulk-pricing-table table {
  text-align: center;
}

/* 
...
*/
```

Working with Spartacus 4.3 and Angular 12. My objective is to:

- keep my custom code as simple and low-specificity as possible
- be able to leverage Bootstrap and Spartacus variables and mixins in my SCSS

Is there a way to ensure my custom styles are rendered last, according to the imports order?

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation they mention wrapping custom styles in the body tag in style.scss.
link [here](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/css-architecture/)

Try wrapping your scss in the body tag. This worked for me.

```
body {
  cx-wish-list-item .cx-return-button .btn-link:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  
  /* My custom code */
  
  header .SiteLogo {
    // width: auto;
    width: 150px;
  }
  
  /* Spartacus defaults continued */
  
  cx-bulk-pricing-table table {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @morganm58 Thank you very much for your suggestion. Your answer does indeed work, because it increases the specificity of the resulting CSS rule (in the compiled CSS it will be `body header .SiteLogo`, which overrides the original `header .SiteLogo` due to higher specificity). I was hoping I could avoid this, since it results in CSS longer and more specific than needed. Nonetheless, I am using this approach currently as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

In order to control the order of styles, it is better to import the styles by yourself.

First, check the angular.json file (as there might be other Spartacus related style files) and keep only one styles file there:

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
```

Then, in styles file import all other styles in required order, e.g.:

```
@import '~@spartacus/styles/index';

@import './styles/custom/_index';
```